# How to chroot Django

Tags: python, django, security, chroot, jail

Can one run Django in a chroot? Notably, what's necessary in order to set up (for example) /var/www as a chroot'd directory and then have Django run in that chroot'd directory?

Thank you - I'm grateful for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add a Python interpreter to that directory and add Django to it ofcourse.

After you've got the environment set-up you will have to create a wrapper script that does something like `os.chroot('/var/www/')` and you're done :)

To create a sandboxed/chrooted environment for Python try one of the following options: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Asking%20for%20Help/How%20can%20I%20run%20an%20untrusted%20Python%20script%20safely%20%28i.e.%20Sandbox%29?highlight=%28chroot%29
The PyPy option seems to be getting popular since Google started using it with the App-Engine.

Comment: @WoLpH: Thanks for the info - that link's broken, though.

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt: the link is fixed again, stackoverflow didn't like the ) in the link ;)

Comment: Great - thanks! That PyPy option is really *very* interesting - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) is preferred for Python web app deployment.  One is stability, another is the variety of configuration options... one of which is ability to chroot the mod_wsgi daemon (starting with version 3.00).

The chroot option is not yet documented for the WSGIDaemonProcess directive at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess but there is enough documentation in [Changes in Version 3.0](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ChangesInVersion0300).

You can also read a disussion of the feature at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=106

Comment: @Van Gale - Thanks - handy reference. We're not using Apache, but Lighttpd (maybe Nginx someday). Is there an equivalent configuration option for Lighttpd that you're aware of (I'm looking now, too)?

Comment: Err, well if you're using lighttpd you're probably also using flup (... and now you have 2 problems ... bada boom ...) fastcgi which means you should be able to have your fastcgi startup/init.d script do the chroot as suggested by WoLpH (although it may be in a shell script instead of python).